# Unexpected String, What's wrong in this code?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I get error when I run the below initialization

```
var data = "<div class='modal fade' id='add_image"+id+"' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'> <div class='modal-dialog'> <div class='modal-content'> <div class='modal-body'> <button type='button' id='close"+id+"' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button> <ul id='tabs' class='nav nav-tabs' data-tabs='tabs'> <li class='active'><a href='#upload"+id+"' data-toggle='tab'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-open'></span> Upload</a></li> <li><a href='#search"+id+"' data-toggle='tab'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span> Search</a></li> </ul> <div id='my-tab-content' class='tab-content'> <div class='tab-pane active' id='upload"+id+"'> <center> <p class='lead' id='q_upload_result"+id+"'></p> <input type='file' name='ques_image"+id+"' id='ques_image"+id+"' data-imgfile=""+id+"" style='visibility:hidden;' onchange='showimagepreview(this);'> <button type='button' id='file_trigger"+id+"' data-tid='"+id+"' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open' onclick='trigger_up(this);'></span> Browse</button> </center> </div> <div class='tab-pane' id='search"+id+"'> <br> <input id='q_search"+id+"' name='q"+id+"' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='search here..'><hr> <span id='img_res"+id+"'></span> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>";
```

for readability:

```
var data = "<div class='modal fade' id='add_image"+id+
    "' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'> <div class='modal-dialog'> <div class='modal-content'> <div class='modal-body'> <button type='button' id='close"+
    id+"' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button> <ul id='tabs' class='nav nav-tabs' data-tabs='tabs'> <li class='active'><a href='#upload"+
    id+"' data-toggle='tab'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-open'></span> Upload</a></li> <li><a href='#search"+id+"' data-toggle='tab'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span> Search</a></li> </ul> <div id='my-tab-content' " +
    " class='tab-content'> <div class='tab-pane active' id='upload"+id+"'> <center> <p class='lead' id='q_upload_result"+
    id+"'></p> <input type='file' name='ques_image"+
    id+"' id='ques_image"+
    id+"' data-imgfile=""+
    id+"" style='visibility:hidden;' onchange='showimagepreview(this);'> <button type='button' id='file_trigger"+id+"' data-tid='"+
    id+"' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open' onclick='trigger_up(this);'></span> Browse</button> </center> </div> <div class='tab-pane' id='search"+
    id+"'> <br> <input id='q_search"+id+"' name='q"+id+"' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='search here..'><hr> <span id='img_res"+id+"'></span> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>";
```

Comment: More code, only from this no one can help you. And what is the error?

Comment: Is it no-indentation-day already?

Comment: @TimZimmermann he's got a 72" wide screen ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoting error is near `..... id+"' data-imgfile=""+id+ ....`

Comment: Thanks amthor ! Works well now !

Comment: Split that into parts or make use of `replace` in order to fiddle the id's in to that, that's likely to become a maintenance nightmare.